# Notify a function in a configuration file that a component is mounted

Tags: reactjs

I have an application which uses Shepherd as walk-through library. In my `Root` component I import the [Shepherd component](https://github.com/shipshapecode/react-shepherd). I pass the configuration of the steps and tour options as props. These configuration variables are placed in a separate file.

**Root.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";    
import App from "./App";
import { ShepherdTour } from 'react-shepherd';
import { tourOptions, steps } from '../utils/shepherd-config';

class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <ShepherdTour steps={steps} tourOptions={tourOptions}>
          <App />
        </ShepherdTour>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Root;
```

**An example of a step configuration:**

```
export const steps = [
    {
        attachTo: { element: '.exampleTemplates', on: 'left' },
        advanceOn: { selector: '.exampleTemplates', event: 'click' },
        beforeShowPromise: function () {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    resolve();
                }, 2500);
            })
        },
        buttons: buttonsForActions,
        title: "Example meeting templates",
        text: ["Here are some example meeting templates. Click on one of them to add them to your current meeting templates so you can edit them later."],
    },
];
```

In Shepherd there is a function, `beforeShowPromise`, in these steps that waits before it attaches the step modal onto an element. As you can see I have currently set a promise to resolve after 2,5 seconds. I did this because the component the step is attached to takes a while to load. But this is something you don't want because internet speed can be slow. So I want to check if a component did mount and notify the function in the configuration that it did so.

[image]

I created some kind of diagram to make it more clear. The application consists of many different components, so I think passing it as state from child to parent is a bit cumbersome. Is there a good, clean solution to let the function in the config file know that the component is mounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with a 'non-react' solution because my config file don't know anything about lifecycle methods. I created a function which checks if the element exist yet, if it doesn't it should check again after 500 milliseconds:

```
function waitForElementToDisplay(selector) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        (function checkIfElementExists() {
            if (document.querySelector(selector) !== null) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                setTimeout(checkIfElementExists, 500);
            }
        })();
    })
}
```

Then in the `beforeShowPromise` function I made the `Promise` function async so it can await until the `waitForElementToDisplay` promise is resolved.

```
  beforeShowPromise: function () {
        return new Promise(async function (resolve) {

            const selector = '.exampleTemplates';

            await waitForElementToDisplay(selector).then(() => {
                resolve();
            });
        })
    },
```